# Order posts by custom post field

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Asked this on another thread and thinking I had gotten a solution marked it as solved.

I have a custom post type called courses and have a field within that called pdf-order that basically represents where in the list the post is going to show. I am trying to get it to sort but am having no luck.

This is my code :

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 30,
                                    'meta_key' => 'pdf-order',
                                    'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
                                    'order' => 'desc' ) );
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your original query is correct.**
But!

I also discovered this today in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

I assume your CF 'pdf-order' are numbers.
But wp orders them alphabetically.
so if we have '1,2,3,10,11'
it will order : 1, 10 , 11, 2, 3
instead of what you would expect (1,2,3,10,11)

So add starting zero's so it would become: '001, 002, 003, 010, 011'

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input mate, but that didn't order my posts correctly. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ordering your posts with numeric values in the Custom Field, you can use `meta_value_num` in place of `meta_value`.

```
$course_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'course',
                                'posts_per_page' => 30,
                                'meta_key' => 'pdf-order',
                                'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',
                                'order' => 'desc' ) );
```